# Unable to find the wrapper “https” - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Tags: php, libcurl, openssl

Ao lançar um script **PHP** tive uma bela surpresa :

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Aqui esta um trecho do meu codigo **PHP**:

```
<?php

$siteUrl = 'http://cnet.com';

$requestUrl = 'https://opengraph.io/api/1.0/site/' . urlencode($siteUrl);

$siteInformationJSON = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
$siteInformation = json_decode($siteInformationJSON, true);
```

Tem alguma extensao faltando ?

Comment: Você precisa da extensão `php_openssl`.

Comment: no stack inglês existe um pergunta similar a sua:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vá no seu arquivo `php.ini` e verifique se a extensão `php_openssl.dll`  está como um `;` (ponto e virgula) na frente. Ai você pode inserir desta forma:

```
extension = php_openssl.dll
```

Feito isso, reinicie o Apache e tente novamente.

Comment: Essa sua resposta me ajudou demais cara. vlw! vlw! ;)